# using multiple java threads CPU usage reach 100%

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-usage

i have created a Download Class extends thread
and it has a randomaccessfile as a  field;

inside the run method i use http Header-Range for different portions to be downloaded by multiple Download Class 
after that i'm  using this while loop.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    InputStream stream = null;
    this.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

    try {
        // Open connection to URL.
            connectionhttp = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connectionhttp.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + start
                    + "-" + end);
            // Connect to server.
            //....
            try {
                connectionhttp.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("connection error");
            }
            //....      
            int contentlength = connectionhttp.getContentLength();

                size = contentlength;

            //....
            stream = connectionhttp.getInputStream();
        }


        while (mainthread.getstatus() == Download.Downloading) {

            if (downloaded == size) {

                break;
            }

            byte buffer[];
            if (size - downloaded >4096) {
                buffer = new byte[4096];

            } else {
                buffer = new byte[(int) (size - downloaded)];

            }

            // read from server into buffer
            int read = stream.read(buffer);
            if (read == -1) {

                break;

            }

            file.write(buffer, 0, read);
            downloaded += read;


        }


    }
```

Now i'm downloading file dividing into 8 portions(each having different range) and thus creating 8 instances for downloading a single file from server.
Because of this my download speed increases up to more than 4-times depending upon server.
Tthe problem is that when i download multiple files , this program makes CPU usage reach upto 100% and thus a lot of  noise from my pc .

Please suggest me a way to optimize my program so that my cpu usage should be less than 10%.
Is there an alternative for Threads for this kind of functionality in java?

Thanks for your Reply!

Comment: I suggest you run your program in a profiler to see what it spending it's time doing.  It is possible the code consuming the CPU is not in this section.

Comment: upto the time i receive http response from the server everything works fine.i've used print statements to log these things.and when it starts to read and write buffers cpu usage reach 100%.After download is finished everything works fine.Is there any way to avoid Threads?

Comment: You can avoid threads by using NIO, however it is highly unlikely to help.  Each thread adds about 0.01% CPU in normal case (a problem if you have 10,000 threads but not 8)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is you are creating a lot of garbage and maxing out the garbage collector.  try recycling your buffer.

```
byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];
while (mainthread.getstatus() == Download.Downloading && downloaded < size) {
    // read from server into buffer
    int read = stream.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length,size-downloaded));
    if (read == -1) break;

    file.write(buffer, 0, read);
    downloaded += read;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, currently the code seems optimized for small values instead of large ones, and the buffer is not reused.